# Typescript Multiple API's updating status in any order

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sabre

I have a typescript project and I am not allowed to load additional 3rd party libraries. I can not use "useEffect" in this project as the vendor is using an older version of React if that matters.
I need to do the following:

1. Make an API call to Get a Token (I can do that)
2. Make 5 different API calls to bring back files (this can be asynchronously done as there's no order for this to be completed)
3. But when any of the API calls resolve then I want to update a progress bar.
4. When all of them have finished I will send them to another screen

I have been struggling with this and I'm trying first to grasp promises without confusing me with async / await. Sorry this is not a specific question but rather a strategy but was hoping someone can help me get further down the road. I'm hoping for an example. The more I read the more confused I get. I am a newbie.

Comment: The question is too complex try separating it into a few smaller ones with reproducible examples

Comment: Yeah, sorry Teneff - you're right...